# Bash script to retrieve value before pattern and output to csv

Tags: bash

I have a text file with the content below:

```
001_Two_Sum.py:48:5: CCR001 Cognitive complexity is too high (5 > 3)
001_Two_Sum.py:61:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
002_Add_Two_Numbers.py:40:5: CCR001 Cognitive complexity is too high (7 > 3)
003_Longest_Substring_Without_Repeating_Characters.py:57:5: CCR001 Cognitive complexity is too 
high (4 > 3)
```

I want to get a csv file that looks like

```
filename,value
001_Two_Sum.py,5
002_Add_Two_Numbers.py,7
003_Longest_Substring_Without_Repeating_Characters.py,4
```

I have the grep command to get the filename `grep -o '\w\+.py' file.txt` and to get the values `grep 'Cognitive complexity is too high (' file.txt | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d\  -f1`. How do I combine these two so that I can get the filename which contains the pattern `CCROO1 Cognitive Complexity`?, i.e., the file name in line 2 is not output since it does not contain the CCROO1... line.
Also how do I output the two values in a csv file appropriately showing the filename and its value?

This is what I came up with

```
filename=$(grep -o '\w\+.py' file.txt)
ccValue=$(grep 'Cognitive complexity is too high (' file.txt | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d\  -f1)

echo "filename,cognitive_complexity" > test.csv; \
echo "$filename,$ccValue" >> test.csv
```

Comment: Which version of grep? `\w` is not standard functionality; POSIX-standardized grep uses BRE or ERE regular expressions, which use `[[:classname:]]` (where a character class name is something like "upper", "lower", "alnum", etc), not backslash-escape sequences which are a PCRE extension.

Comment: (and think about using `awk` instead of `grep | cut | cut` in general; awk can do everything grep can do _and_ everything cut can do all in one statement).

Comment: I've edited the question to be inclusive of other commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
awk -F '[:(>]' -vOFS=, 'BEGIN {print "filename", "value"} $4 ~ /Cognitive complexity/ {print $1, $5}'
```

Comment: Thank you. Please explain what is happening in the command. `awk -F '[:(>]' -vOFS=, 'BEGIN {print "filename", "value"} $4 ~ /Cognitive complexity/ {print $1, $5}' filetoread.txt > filetooutput.csv`

Comment: `awk` splits the lines using the chars in `:(>`, prints the header and then if the field 4 matches "Cognitive complexity" prints fields 1 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command should do the trick:

```
sed -n 's/\([^:]*\).*CCR001 Cognitive complexity is too high (\([0-9]*\).*/\1,\2/p' file
```